# Role of qubit registers in HHL circuit

Tags: quantum-circuit, hhl-algorithm

I'm trying to figure out how the HHL algorithm works from reading Dervovic's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08227) and IBM's [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20220223194820/https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html).

Dervovic shows the following HHL circuit in Fig 5:

[image: dervovic]

whereas IBM uses:

[image: ibm]

I want to clarify the IBM circuit.

- The $\vert{0}\rangle$ is the ancilla register (stores eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ after doing $R$ rotation), $\vert{0}\rangle$ with $n_l$ corresponds to the clock register (stores eigenvalues of $A$), and $\vert{0}\rangle$ with $n_b$ corresponds to the input register (stores solution $x$). Is this correct?
- What is the purpose of the $\vert{0}\rangle$ register with $n_a$? It doesn't seem to be referenced in the IBM text.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>community wiki</sup>

---

Your first bullet is probably correct, although I wouldn't refer to the one single qubit $|0\rangle$ at the top as storing eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ - the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are stored in the $n_l$ clock qubits after rotation.  The single qubit at the top is used as a flag register to tell whether post-selection succeeded or not. This one qubit is register $S$ in Dervovic's circuit.

Also the $n_a$ qubits are probably an ancillary register for the state preparation and the Hamiltonian simulation used in the phase estimation and rotation/inversion.  This is probably the "extra register" referred to in the tutorial. They always are uncomputed and revert back to $|0\rangle$ - after state preparation, and again after each time-step in the Hamiltonian simulation.  Dervovic ignores these auxiliary ancilla qubits (but they are implicitly there).